# Toshiba Satellite L855-14J and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, laptop, toshiba-satellite

I have Toshiba Satellite L855 with Intel i7 3630QM and AMD 7670M. This version is called L855-14J here, in Croatia.

It also came with 4GB of RAM and 750 GB HDD and 1366 x 768 LED display.

I had some problems when installing and making Ubuntu 12.10 normal working environment:

- Wired network didn't worked
- USB 3.0 didn't worked
- No Intel HD graphic from i7 was present
- Fglrx drivers had problems
- Brightness couldn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I've managed to fix almost every problem I encountered.

- **Wired network**: As I could make normal installation with wirelles working out of the box, this wasn't a big issue. You can check with `lspci` that network card used in that laptop is Atheros AR8161. Fix this by installing `linux-backports-modules-cw-*` for your kernel (you can check it by typing `uname -a` - mine was 3.5.0-19-generic)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-19-generic
  ```

  and running

  ```
  sudo modprobe alx
  ```
- **USB 3.0**: I wanted to use external HDD with USB 3.0 enclosure but I found it not working. For this problem I don't blame Ubuntu (Linux) because I haven't managed to find any other working USB 3.0 device so I can check it. It may be some problem with enclosure or powering USB port, because it is working with desktop and Windows 7. If I find more, I'll post and update.

  As this laptop comes with only one USB 2.0 port and two USB 3.0 ports, I found useful to disable USB 3.0 in BIOS is order to make it behave like USB 2.0.
- **No Intel HD graphic**: I was hoping that I could use i7 built-in HD 4000 GPU with Intel open-source drivers for general usage and saving battery life, but I was wrong. This time it's Toshibas bad idea to make graphic non-switchable, so laptop can only use AMD graphic, not i7s one. **Be careful** if you intend to buy Toshiba laptops and want to have both GPUs as it seams that this is theirs general practice.
- **Fglrx drivers**: I managed to make it working by installing fglrx from repository. It seams that `fglrx` package wasn't compatibile with this kernel or X (I don't really know for sure) but `fglrx-updates` package did the trick. So:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
  ```

  and don't forget to

  ```
  sudo aticonfig --initial
  ```

  and **reboot**.

  After this process, I got scared because whole screen was tearing hard and was really unusable. Fortunately, this fixed it. Open `amdcccle` and in *Display options* -> *Tear free* enable *Tear Free Desktop to reduce tearing*. Also, In *3D* -> *More settings* put *Wait for vertical refresh* to *Always on*.

  If everything was OK `fglrxinfo` should give you
- **Brightness**: With default open-source drivers, brightness changing didn't worked, but with fglrx working everything was ok.

Also, in case someone is interested, I've added 4GB RAM more and changed built-in HDD for SDD. Laptop performances are quite impressive and one feels more productive in such fast enviroment - it boots in Ubuntu for ~6 seconds.

Only bigger downside, with missing Intel HD graphics, is low battery life. Best result was almost 2h with low display brightness and using only terminals and Firefox.